# How to implement same customized log through differents files via logging module

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, singleton, python-logging

I believe from other questions I have read that logging has a singleton pattern but I did not succeed to implement it right.

I have a `logger.py` file like this :

```
import logging
import os
from concurrent_log_handler import ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler


def create_file_handler(path, filename=None):
    if filename is None:
        filename = f"app_{os.getlogin()}"
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s |  %(name)s | %(funcName)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s')
    file_handler = ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler(fr'{path}\{filename}.log', mode='a', maxBytes=1024*1024*10, # 10 Mo per file
                                 backupCount=10)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    return file_handler
```

Let's say to simplify that I have two other files, `file_one.py` (the file I will call first) which uses functions from `file_two.py`.

I would like a custom log file from `file_one.py`, so I have created log like this in it :

```
import logging
from logger import create_file_handler

file_handler = create_file_handler(r'C:\custom\path', filename="custom_filename")
le_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
le_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

le_log.addHandler(file_handler)
```

The problem is that in `file_two.py` I can't put the custom path neither the custom_file_name in argument of `create_file_handler` because I don't know in advance which file (there is not only `file_one.py`) will call the functions in `file_two.py`.
So how do I use the customized `le_log` from `file_one.py` when using functions from `file_two.py` ?

Currently I do a default logger creation in `file_two.py` because I need a `le_log` variable in the file.

Comment: Couple of questions:
**1)** Are all the log names in both `file_one.py` and `file_two.py` going to have a common prefix in their name? (the `__name__` used in `.getLogger(__name__)`) For instance, something like `TmSmth.my_packages.file_one` and `TmSmth.my_packages.file_two`... ? I'm asking because log configuration is hierarchical and maybe they can be applied to all logs under `TmSmth.` or `TmSmth.my_packages`. Also **2)** Do you have the ability to edit the log's name in your `file_two.py`? I mean... Can you change the log creation in `file_two.py` to `logging.getLogger("a_name_I_know")` ?

Comment: 1) No, they have not the same prefix
2) Neither and it was the main issue, because as i don't know in advance the name of the file which calls `file_two.py`, i can't do something like `logging.getLogger("name_of_file_which_calls")`
But i have found a solution i'll post in answer later !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best practice but I finally succeed to do it.
In `file_one.py` i put :

```
import logging
from logs.logger import create_file_handler

file_handler = create_file_handler(r'C:\custom\path', filename="custom_filename")
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[file_handler])
le_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
le_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

I used the customized handler in the `.basicConfig()` method of `logging` instead of adding to `le_log` with `.addHandler()`. I guess it allows the `logging` class to spread through others files called in `file_one.py`. Then in `file_two.py` I put :

```
import logging
le_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
le_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```